# Populating PDF Form using iTextSharp and Unicode characters

Tags: c#, vb.net, unicode, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following:

- A PDF Form created with Adobe Acrobat X (all fields use Helvetica & Helvetica Bold)
- A VB.NET project where I try to populate the PDF and then flatten it

What happens it the following:

- All fields gets filled out according to my wishes.

BUT as soon as someone from for example Norway tries this it all goes wrong. As soon as they
use some of the special characters they use (æ,ø etc) those chars are just left out. If I try using them when filling it out manually in Adobe Reader everything is fine though.

I've tried using the following:

```
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\Windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

And

```
pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("txtDistrict", "textfont", bf, Nothing)
```

Which worked, it also works using Arial in Adobe Acrobat when creating the PDF form, however the sheer size of the file is staggering, it goes from 25 kb to 1,5 mb if I do it in Acrobat and from 25 kb to 840 kb if I use the basefont.create method.

Isn't there a better way of accomplishing this? The reason I ask is because the web app I'm creating might have to merge upwards of 50 of these pdf-files to one file for download and then the size really becomes critical, especially if the size bumps from 1,25 mb to 50+ mb for ONE file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.